How do I handle an oauth2 callback from an Azure Function?
I have an Azure Function which is timer based.  Absolutely no user interaction.  I need to access an API which uses oauth2.  I have to pre-register the callback address with their company, then pass it along with the auth request.
I don't know how to handle this in Azure.  Can a function even have a callback address since it is a transient process?  If so, where do I go in Azure to set it?
I've been beating around this problem for a while now, and I feel like I'm missing some key element that I need...

You should preferably use the clients-credentials flow to authenticate from your function to your API. This flow is more suitable when you have no user involved. Otherwise the Oauth authentication is a statefull process. I blogged about that here https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/

I agree with @Tore Nestenius when there is no user interaction involved, you can make use of Clients Credentials flow to authenticate from function to the API.

If you are making use of Clients Credentials flow then you need to grant Application type API permissions.

For sample, I generated access token using Postman by passing parameters like below:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:Secret
scope:api://xxx/.default
grant_type:client_credentials



Refer: Client Credentials Flow - Call Web API to API without user interaction (c-sharpcorner.com) by Vikas Hooda
If the above doesn’t meet your requirement, then make use of User interactive flow: OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow with a React SPA, ASP.NET Core Web API, RBAC roles, and MSAL – 1.21 kilobytes (keithbabinec.com)
